# How to output a new dataframe with mismatched columns from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I want to have a function that creates a new dataframe from two dataframes.
I want to show the mismatched columns based on id number and a given column.
[image]
dataframes as input:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
    'first_column': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'],
    'second_column': ['1', '2', '2'],
    'third_column': ['1', '2', '2'],
    'fourth_column': ['1', '2', '1']
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
print("\n")
print("df1")
print(df1)



data2 = {
    'first_column': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4'],
    'second_column': ['3', '4', '2', '2'],
    'third_column': ['1', '2', '2', '2'],
    'fourth_column': ['1', '2', '2', '2']
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STEP 1 // add the table name Prefix on column name

```
df1.columns = df1.columns + '_df1'
df2.columns = df2.columns + '_df2'
```

STEP 2 // Concat both df

```
data = pd.concat([df1.set_index('first_column_df1'),df2.set_index('first_column_df2')],axis=1, join='outer').reset_index()
```

STEP 3 // Using lambda function findout which row second column does math if does match return True and print only DF rows where condition came True

```
data = data[data.apply(lambda x: x.second_column_df1 != x.second_column_df2 ,axis=1)]
```

STEP 4 // To achieve desire output

```
data[['index', 'second_column_df1', 'second_column_df2']].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    index   second_column_df1   second_column_df2
0   id1     1                   3
1   id2     2                   4
2   id4     NaN                 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, according to step 3 isn't it : Using lambda function findout which row second column does math if does match return True and print only DF rows where condition came "False" and not True ?

Comment: Yes, you understood correct.

Answer (score 1):

Is that something you were looking for:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('first_column')
df2 = df2.set_index('first_column')
    
df1.columns = df1.columns + '_df1'
df2.columns = df2.columns + '_df2'

df_out = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)
```

Which gives you:
[image]

If you're bothered about first_column in the index:

```
df_out = df_out.reset_index(inplace = False)
```

Which gives you:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! yes something like this but only with the mismatch!